# ARCGIS Suvery123 Connect can create feature service is only hosted feature layer and How to solve problem?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-online

1. This is hosted feature layer have enable editing
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSiwi.png
2. This is non hosted feature layer from database (I enable edit everything before publish) don't have enable editing
   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RInkX.png
   so I can't solve following up with ARCGIS technical article because I use non hosted feature layer
   [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzenk.png

Comment: Does you layer have __Global ID__?, it is required

Comment: Yes, I added Global ID before publish.

Comment: Double check all requirements, take a look at this links, [Survey123 - With existing FeatureLayer](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/desktop/create-surveys/survey123withexistingfeatureservices.htm), [Survey123 Blog - Enable Supports Apply Edits With Global Ids](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-blog/how-to-enable-supportsapplyeditswithglobalids-on/ba-p/893977)

Comment: Thank you so much, I try to follow your step, but I think I have problem about license